# Is i possible to call t() instead of I18n.t() in javascript?

Tags: javascript, function, module, internationalization

I am using [i18n-js](https://github.com/fnando/i18n-js) to load locales in to my js app. When I use the translate function in my view I would like to be able to just say `t('Hello')` instead of `I18n.t('Hello')`. How can I get such an alias to work?

```
import I18n from 'i18n';

const Hello = () => {
  return (
    <div>{I18n.t("hello", {name: "John"})}</div>
  )
}
```

Comment: The most "secure" method is `var t = I18n.t.bind(I18n);`. There may or may not be a shorter method depending on how the module is structured exactly.

Comment: Cool. I put it in a `locales.js` file and did `module.exports = {I18n, t};` so I only have to require that one file. That seems to work fine.

Comment: Or rather, only have to import that one function in my component files.

Comment: @deceze: Mind if I add that to my answer? (Or you should add it as an answer, since it's the best option)

Comment: @Cerbrus Do what you will. :) I'll leave this as comment, since there may or may not be a better way to import just that method; this would require having a deeper look at the library, which I won't do right now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You *could* assign the `t` function to [`window`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window):

```
window.t = I18n.t;
```

Then you can just use `t('Hello')`. However, as @[Thilo](https://stackoverflow.com/users/14955/thilo) [mentioned](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36834438/is-i-possible-to-call-t-instead-of-i18n-t-in-javascript/36834476#comment61240507_36834476), this may result in some complications.

---

A better alternative is to write a small wrapper:

```
function t(key){
    return I18n.t(key);
}
```

---

The *best* option, [suggested](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36834438/is-i-possible-to-call-t-instead-of-i18n-t-in-javascript#comment61239625_36834438) by @[deceze](https://stackoverflow.com/users/476/deceze), would be this single line:

```
var t = I18n.t.bind(I18n);
```

Single-line, and should work regardless of the scope it's called in.

Comment: If you do that, make sure that `I18n` was not a "class instance" whose methods wanted to make use of `this` (to look up locales or configuration or such).

Comment: `var t = I18n.t.bind(I18n);` is the best and clearest choise

Comment: where to add this `var t = I18n.t.bind(I18n);` ?